# Como Achar o ultimo numero da tabela no SQL e somar +1

Tags: c#, sql

sou iniciante em programação e preciso de ajuda com esse caso, tenho um Datagridview que vai ser carregado com dados de um banco de dados e com base nesse dados será inserido em um outro banco, porem algumas colunas precisam ter valores padrões, existe uma que estou com problemas, eu preciso achar o ultimo valor dessa tabela e somar mais + 1 sempre que adicionar uma nova linha de dados, eu consegui fazer isso no banco mas no C# não, ou seja, como eu faria essa Select, armazenaria em uma variável ? como eu passaria essa variável como referencia dentro da Select principal ? segue um print de como esta minha Select, ali esta como @Maximo pq tentei fazer um parâmetro pra ela mas não consegui Obrigado!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, antes da string do insert, você pode fazer algo como:

```sql
select max(REFERENCIA) + 1 as maximo from LANCAMENTO_CONTABIL
```

salva o valor retornado do select numa variável e concatena ela no insert

Se quiser dar uma olhada melhor:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não recomendo esse tipo de abordagem, salvo raríssimas exceções! Os ambiente são de múltiplos acessos e há uma enorme probabilidade desse "MAX" se repetir devido ao tempo de processamento Banco x Aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

No banco de dados existe um mecanismo, no meu caso eu uso o Mysql/MariaDB, que é o AUTO_INCREMENT.
Este mecanismo é no campo que usa para controlar o numero do Registro.
É bom criar um campo chamado ID na tabela, e neste campo liga o AUTO_INCREMENT.
Então quando criar um novo registro este campo já ganha um numero sequencial automaticamente.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).